# Trying to have a socket server make instances of clients to connect

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, client

The basic idea is to run the server the server then instances one or two clients that will then run and connect to the server and start a new thread. When the server gets a new connection it creates a new thread to put that connection on. It works fine if I individually run the server and the client, but not when I have the server instance the client.I dont know where I am going wrong here. I am doing this for a final project for class and dont have much networking/socket programming background. Please help.

Server Code:

```
import socket
from _thread import *
from ClientTest2 import ClientTest2

def multi_threaded_client(connection):
    connection.send(str.encode('Server is working:'))
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(2048)
        response = 'Server message: ' + data.decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
            break
        connection.sendall(str.encode(response))
    connection.close()

def newProcess(test):
    c1 = ClientTest2("test")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ServerSideSocket = socket.socket()
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 2004
    ThreadCount = 0
    try:
        ServerSideSocket.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))
    print('Socket is listening..')
    ServerSideSocket.listen(5)
    c1 = ClientTest2()


    while True:
        Client, address = ServerSideSocket.accept()
        print('Connected to: ' + address[0] + ':' + str(address[1]))
        start_new_thread(multi_threaded_client, (Client,))
        ThreadCount += 1
        print('Thread Number: ' + str(ThreadCount))
    ServerSideSocket.close()
```

Client Code:

```
import socket

class ClientTest2():
    ClientMultiSocket = socket.socket()
    host = '127.0.0.1'
    port = 2004
    print('Waiting for connection response')
    try:
        ClientMultiSocket.connect((host, port))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))
    res = ClientMultiSocket.recv(1024)
    Input = 'Hey there: '
    while True:
        ClientMultiSocket.send(str.encode(Input))
        res = ClientMultiSocket.recv(1024)
    print(res.decode('utf-8'))
    ClientMultiSocket.close()
```